# htaccess correction, following by high performance book of oreilly

Tags: .htaccess

I tried to add this in my htaccess and it gave an error, I'm a total newb on the server side scripting, is there any editor for correcting?

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
mod_gzip_on
mod_gzip_item_include mod_gzip_item_include mod_gzip_item_include mod_gzip_item_include file    \.js$
mod_gzip_item_include   mime    ^application/x-javascript$
mod_gzip_item_include   file    \.css$
mod_gzip_item_include   mime    ^text/css$
mod_gzip_item_include reqheader "User-Agent: MSIE [6-9]" 
mod_gzip_item_include reqheader "User-Agent: Mozilla/[5-9]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mod_gzip_item_include mod_gzip_item_include mod_gzip_item_include mod_gzip_item_include
```

it should be only one of them, remove the excessive 3

Comment: still not working, do I have to put into a bracket? something like <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> or something like that

Comment: another approach is, to remove all the lines, and put them back one by one, until it dies again, maybe there's only one line which is the culprit

Comment: thanx bro, I tried every single one of them. it doesn't seem to work. I guess I dont have mod_gzip installed -_-<

Comment: it's a linux box, or some wamp installation?

Comment: its godaddy linux, deluxe hosting plan

Comment: in this case you may be able to configure it through cpanel.